# ReactJS Material UI how to prevent Autocomplete to change the value

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete component and I need to prevent it for selecting some kind of values.

```
const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"];

const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

const change = (event, newValue) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (newValue !== "Option 3") {
    setValue(newValue);
  }
};

console.log(value);

return (
  <div>
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={change}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
      }}
      id="controllable-states-demo"
      disableClearable
      options={options}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Currently the condition does not change the state, but it does change the value on the component. How can I prevent this to happen?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uojwl?file=/demo.js) is the sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting value again here, dont update on this event

```
onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
   setInputValue(newInputValue);
}}
```

set inputValue={value}

Updated here,
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jmr6e?file=/demo.js